# Radix UI Theme: how to create a topbar

Tags: radix-ui

I'm wondering how to properly create a topbar using Radix UI Theme.
It doesn't seem to have such a property.

- Should I do it myself with a custom CSS?
- Does Radix includes something to have a topbar?

The only thing that could be close to it seems to be [this](https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/navigation-menu), unfortunately this component is not included in radix.

What is the proper way to develop a topbar with radix?